# How to add diferent text for each element in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, loops, dom, innerhtml

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this code. I want to add a number from 0 to 4, but it added only the last number from my loop.
Thank you very much in advance.

```
<script>
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      var createEl = i;
      var createEl = document.createElement("li");
      for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        createEl.innerHTML = [j];
        }
      console.log(createEl); 
      //<li>4</li>
      //<li>4</li>
      //<li>4</li>
      //<li>4</li>
      //<li>4</li>
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need the nested for loop just use the i value from the first loop

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   var createEl = document.createElement("li");
   createEl.innerHTML = i;
   console.log(createEl); 
}
```

This will only print the tags to console. In case you want to put them in another tag use it like this:

```
var node = document.createElement("div");
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   var createEl = document.createElement("li");
   createEl.innerHTML = i;
   node.appendChild(createEl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two loops for that.

```
var ulContainer = document.createElement("ul"); 

for (i=0; i < 5; i++) {
var createEl = document.createElement("li");
  createEl.innerHTML = i;
  ulContainer.appendChild(createEl); 
}
```